# Celery class based task apply_async

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have my class inherited from `celery.task.PeriodicTask` and i want to run this task asynchoronously sometimes.

If it was a usual method task, i did something like:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=15))
def mytask(additional=False):
    if a==b and not additional:
        # args = [True,] sets additional=True
        mytask.apply_async(args=[True, ], countdown=7*60)
```

But now i have a class:

```
from celery.task import PeriodicTask
class MyClassTask(PeriodicTask):
    def run(self, additional=False):
        if a == b and not additional:
            self.apply_async(task_id=self.request.id, args=[True, ], countdown=7*60)
```

**EDIT: CODE IS WORKING OK. I checked and question is no longer needed.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I double checked manually and my code works, anyone can do like this:

```
from celery.task import PeriodicTask
class MyClassTask(PeriodicTask):
    def run(self, additional=False):
        if a == b and not additional:
            self.apply_async(task_id=self.request.id, args=[True, ], countdown=7*60)
```